# Отличие интерфейса Serializable от магических методов __sleep и __wakeup

Tags: php

В чем отличие интерфейса Serializable от от магических методов __sleep и __wakeup  ?

По сути они же выполняют одну и туже задачу? Что лучше использовать и в каких случаях?

Answer (score 0):

- Есть чёткий приоритет, если все эти методы есть в классе.

  1. __serialize
  2. Serializable::serialize
  3. __sleep

  После нахождения первого попавшегося последующие не будут выполняться.
- __serialize (появилась с 7.4) - должен возвращать ассоциативный массив с **любыми данными**, которые нужно сериализовать, он будет сериализован обычной функцией [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)
- Serializable::serialize (устарел с 8.1) - должен возвращать строку с любыми сериализоваными данными, совсем не обязательно с помощью serialize(), это может быть **любой формат**, например JSON, потому что он будет немного короче, или URL-кодированную строку, или base64.
- __sleep - должен возвращать массив с **именами свойств объекта**, которые будут сериализованы обычной функцией [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)

Методы __unserialize, Serializable::unserialize, __wakeup аналогичны только из сериализованных данных инициализируют объект (восстанавливают свойства, указатели ресурсов, БД, файлов и т.д.).

Answer (score -1):

Из документации:

Предполагаемое использование __sleep() состоит в завершении работы над данными, ждущими обработки или других подобных задач очистки. Кроме того, этот метод может полезен, когда есть очень большие объекты, которые нет необходимости полностью сохранять.

С другой стороны, функция unserialize() проверяет наличие метода с магическим именем __wakeup(). Если она имеется, эта функция может восстанавливать любые ресурсы, которые может иметь объект.

Предполагаемое использование __wakeup() заключается в восстановлении любых соединений с базой данных, которые могли быть потеряны во время операции сериализации и выполнения других операций повторной инициализации.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup